# css theming in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, layout

I have a wordpress theme that has a back-end layout styler that allows me to easily change the font, color, & look of my site. Its nice and all however the customization ends up in a `<style> </style>` tag in the template; inside the header. How can I tell it to save to a "custom.css" instead? The theme I'm referring to is WooThemes- Canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to dig into the php of the theme and redesign how it works, leave it the way it is. Functionally, it's not that bad. It may not be pretty, but many frameworks do custom CSS that way.